# Add Date time automatically in blog post

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, blog, hide-elements

[image]

In the screen shot above, there is a DateTime control field in the Form. Currently users set the values manually and then publish the post.

I want the Published Date to be set automatically and hide the DateTime control from the form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, the "published" field will select the current date-time at time of publishing, by default? What is it you want to change?

Comment: Currently user have to select the date time when he going to publish a post.Please refer the attached image. I want remove that date time controls from the blog post and input date time automatically.

Comment: as per your comment TRS, you only want to hide the date-time control on the form?

Comment: I want to enter "published" date time automatically,at time of publishing.thank you

Comment: yes zakir.And need to automatically insert date time without the user selections.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps that @George mentioned is half a way correct. But the problem is if you hide **Published** column from the content type **Post** then its value will also hide from list view and post both. You can test this by creating a post in your blog and you will not see the date-time on the post.

There is a trick here to get the date-time on the post without **Published** field being available to the user.

Create a SPD workflow to publish on **Post** list. In this workflow simply create one step to update the **Published** field value with **Modified** field value as show in below image. Ensure to only select "*Start the workflow automatically when an item is created*" at the Start Options in SPD.

Now create a post after publishing the workflow and you will see the date-time on your post and even in the list view with **Published** column being unavailable to the author.

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't, it hides it from the form. You can still see the published date in a view.

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger you can perform the test at your side what you mention in your answer. And you would see no date-time on your post and even in your list view.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. Seems an oversight by SharePoint. @TRS - JavaScript  would be your alternative here, to hide the Published field whilst still retaining the value

Answer (score 2):

Ahh I see, in response to your comment above then:

Go to the **Advanced Settings** of this list, set **Allow Management of Content Types** equal to **Yes**. Click on the **Post** content type, click on the **Published** column, and select **Hidden**.

The user will no longer have the option to set the published date/time. Note that it will still be set, but will be set the default *current* time.